# String comparison behaves differently

Tags: php, string, equality, string-comparison

```
$x = array(3) {
   [0]=>       "A - 1"
   [1]=>       "B - 4"
   ["Total"]=>     "5"
 }
```

TRY:

```
foreach($x as $k=>$v){
   if($k=="Total"){break;}
    echo $v."<br>";
 }
```

Because I just want to output :

```
A - 1
B - 4
```

But I don't see anything in the output.

what do I wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get nothing in the output as you break out of the loop the very fist time.

In the first iteration `$k` with value `0` which is numeric is compared with `"Total"` which is a string and this comparison returns `true` because PHP will convert the string `"total"` to a number before comparison and `"total"` when converted to number is `0`.

[Ideone](http://www.ideone.com/gtm7c)

To fix this don't use `==`, use `strcmp` instead which will convert the numeric keys to string before comparison or you can use `===` which checks type as well as value.

[Ideone](http://www.ideone.com/GvNxH)

Comment: I dont know it is support the php 5.3 or not? currently I am using 5.3

Comment: you can also use $k==="Total" ... (=== - equal type and content)

Comment: @n00b: You are right. I've added that to my answer and +1 to you.

Answer (score -1):

Put `echo $v."<br>";` in an else statement......